# Is it possible to configure GCC to compile for android?

Tags: android, c, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which compiler does Android NDK use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602929/which-compiler-does-android-ndk-use)

I am wondering if it is possible to compile a Native Android Application through GCC. Is this even possible? o.O

Comment: Please see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602929/which-compiler-does-android-ndk-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in principle, but Android is designed to run on many mobile platforms, while gcc will target only one of them at a time.  The application therefore will not be portable, and it will be closer to truth to say that it runs on ARM Linux (for example) than that it runs on Android.

There is additional detail with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1002164/1235565) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6602929/1235565) question.  **Edit**: I had first misread that to mean that the NDK is not compatible with stock gcc, but upon a closer look, it is compatible.  People however normally use the slightly modified gcc that is included with the NDK itself which is how you would normally develop a native application.

The caveat about long term portability still applies.

Comment: This is completely wrong: You can compile programs without problems using GCC. People do this all the time when they use the Android NDK. And they run very well even on non-rooted machines.